# Find $x \in \mathbb{C}^N$ that solves $z = \text{diag}(M x) x^*$ given $z \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ and the non-singular marix $M \in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, matrix-equations

I want to find the complex vector $x$ of length $N$ which solves

$$ z = \text{diag}(M x) x^*$$

where the complex vector $z$ of size $N$ as well as the complex, non-singular $N\times N$ matrix M are given. Note that $x^*$ is the complex conjugate of $x$.

Alternatively, the diagonalized vector may be shifted by a real scalar value $\lambda$ such that

$$ z = \text{diag}(M x + \lambda) x^*$$

I imagine the solution $(x)$ or $(x, \lambda)$ to be degenerate. In this case, the question would be what is one possible solution, *ie* the principal value of the solution?

Comment: I don't think there's a general solution (also what do you mean by a degenerate solution?). For example, take $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $z=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.